# Angular APP_INITIALIZER not delaying bootstrapping on success

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use APP_INITIALIZER to make Angular delay boostrapping until I can grab some environment variables.

I've read and followed numerous tutorials and Stack Overflow answers on this and none of them are matching what I'm seeing.

APP_INITIALIZER does work, in that it prevents the page from loading if the promise rejects, but on success, it doesn't.  Rather, the console logging indicates that the other services which depend on the initialisation service attempt to use it before it completes and you can imagine all the hilarity than ensues loading all the things that don't exist.

The internet and the documentation swear this works.  Here's my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface IAppConfigDetails {
  environment: any;
  apiUrls: Array<string>;
  googleAnalyticsEnabled: boolean;
}

export const appEnvironmentFactory = (appConfig: AppConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return appConfig.loadEnvironment();
  };
};

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  private appConfig: IAppConfigDetails = {
    environment: {},
    apiUrls: [],
    googleAnalyticsEnabled: false,
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadEnvironment() {
    console.log('loadEnvironment called');

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('/assets/environment.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then((data: any ) => {
          // console.log('About to set environment');
          // console.log(data);
          this.appConfig.environment = data['environment'];
          this.appConfig.apiUrls = data['API_URLS'];
          this.appConfig.googleAnalyticsEnabled = data['GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ENABLED'];
          resolve(this.appConfig);
          // console.log('Environment fetched');
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(
            'Environment definition not found.' +
            'If you\'re running this locally, try calling make_environment.sh to generate a new environment file.'
          );
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });

    return promise;
  }

  getConfig(): IAppConfigDetails {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}
```

and is used for example in:

```
@Injectable()
export class EnvironmentService {

  private microservices: IMicroservice[] = [];
  private environment: { [index: string]: any } = {};

  constructor(
    protected appConfigService: AppConfigService,
  ) {
    const appConfig = appConfigService.getConfig(); // <- Line 22
    console.log('App config is:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify( appConfig, null, 4 ));
    console.log('App config environment is:');
    console.log(appConfig.environment);
    this.environment = Object.assign({}, appConfig.environment);
    console.log('this.environment:');
    console.log(this.environment);
  }

  ...
}
```

console logging indicates that appConfig is defaultly configured at the time when the environment service wants it and loads after the service has initialised.

Console log:

```
App config is:
environment.service.ts:24 {
    "environment": {},
    "apiUrls": [],
    "googleAnalyticsEnabled": false
}
environment.service.ts:25 App config environment is:
environment.service.ts:26 Object
environment.service.ts:28 this.environment:
environment.service.ts:29 Object
app-config.service.ts:27 loadEnvironment called
```

and provider reference:

```
  providers: [
    ...
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appEnvironmentFactory,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    }
    ...
  ]
```

Comment: How your providers section looks in the module?

Comment: Could you include the log output in your question?  Would be helpful to get an idea of the sequence of events

Comment: @robert added requested information

Comment: @JonathanSeed added requested information

Comment: Providers section looks ok. I use it the same way. The only difference is that in my app I make initial data requests from "AppConfig" service calling other services etc. In your case you initiate data requests from "EnvironmentService" constructor which is too early. I would change it to call EnvironmentService's "load" method from your "AppConfig" service once "environment.json" is received.

Comment: @robert Thanks.  I think I diverged from you by injecting my configuration service into my applications sub-dependencies, so it starts up the configuration before it should.  Your solution, to 'load' the services inside the configuration is probably the simplest one.  I went a different way, but it was helpful to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found some traction on this issue in: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279 which I really recommend reading.

As a summary, APP_INITIALISER won't guarantee that your configuration service completes first, especially if you inject the service it's providing into your sub-modules.  You may be able to get around this, apparently (I haven't tested this) by making sure your application modules don't depend on the provided service, which pushes other modules to be executed too early.

But, the best way, if you absolutely need a configuration service to run before Angular wants to use it, is to modify your main.ts to delay Angular bootstrapping. 
 Then you can depend on the configuration service to your heart's content. (Thanks to https://github.com/rehfeldchris and their comment in the thread).

An example in practise is:

```
main.ts

function bootstrapFailed(val: any) {
    document.getElementById('bootstrap-fail').style.display = 'block';
    console.error('bootstrap-fail', val);
}

// If the environment is set to boostrap
if ( environment.bootstrapping && environment.bootstrapping.configuration) {
 fetch('assets/configuration.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(config => {
        if (!config ) {
            bootstrapFailed(config);
            return;
        }

        // Store the response somewhere that your ConfigService can read it.
      (<any>window)['tempConfigStorage'] = config;

        platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch(bootstrapFailed);
    })
    .catch(bootstrapFailed);
} else {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(bootstrapFailed);
}
```

```
configuration.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
  /*
  Configuration service is guaranteed to have run before Angular bootstraps itself.
   */
  public appConfig: IAppConfigDetails = {
    environment: {},
    apiUrls: [],
    googleAnalyticsEnabled: false,
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  initConfig( jsonData: any) {
    if (jsonData) {
      this.appConfig.environment = jsonData.environment;
      this.appConfig.apiUrls = jsonData.API_URLS;
      this.appConfig.googleAnalyticsEnabled = jsonData.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ENABLED;
    }
  }

  getConfig(): IAppConfigDetails {
    return this.appConfig;
  }
}

export function configurationFactory() {
  const service = new ConfigurationService();
  service.initConfig((<any>window)['tempConfigStorage']);
  return service;
}
```